# Text output on an AndroidApp

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to program an android App with AndroidStudio. It is like an calculator and i don't know how to print the answer on my screen. I tried it with System.out.println() but it doesn't work Log._() doesn't work too.

Comment: try to show your code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display a temporary pop-up message to the screen using a Toast as below:

```
Toast.makeText(context,"<Message here>", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If you want the text to persist, then use a TextView object. Add it to your .xml for that activity:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then declare it in your Activity screen:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

Then set the text using .setText(), probably in the onClick() method of whatever button you're using to calculate the result for the user:

```
myTextView.setText(calculatorResult);
```

Comment: thanks does it stay on the screen or is it just temporary on the screen ?

Comment: No, a toast only appears for a certain duration, either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG. If you want to have it persist on the screen you'd have to use something else like a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) that displays the answer.

Comment: No problem. Consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you found it worked for you so that people know the question has been solved.